# How to get particular string form a string

Tags: java

```
String text = "Thanx for purchasing this, Rs. 1000. Thanx for visiting";
```

I need double value from the above string. 
Length is not fixed of Rs. value (`1000`).

How to get this value?

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4662215/how-to-extract-a-substring-using-regex
You will need a different regex but that's the approach I'd go with

Comment: take a look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25225475/getting-a-substring-from-a-string-after-a-particular-word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to use `java regex`

Here is sample code 
Regex pattern will change based on  your requirement simple regex to get only double value `"\\d+\\.\\d+"`

```
String line = "Thanx for purchasing this, Rs. 1000. Thanx for visiting";
        String regex = "[+-]?\d*\.?\d+([eE][+-]?\d+)?";

        String[] str = line.split(regex);
```

Other wise you can try below code

```
public String drawDigitsFromString(String strValue){
            String str = strValue.trim();
            String digits="";
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                char chrs = str.charAt(i);              
                if (Character.isDigit(chrs))
                    digits = digits+chrs;
            }
            return digits;
        }
```

I think this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

if there is no other number then After Rs. you can use

```
text.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
```

if there is some other number also, it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an array of all the words and the use only the number like this:

```js
var text = "Thanx for purchasing this, Rs. 1000. Thanx for visiting";

var array = text.split(" ");
var newText = array[5].replace(".","");

console.log(newText)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Text can any number space, so we can split using space and take array[5] element